# Include a Deep Link URL within my QR Code

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

Within my `iOS` app, I am generating a QR code where the base functionality is just to move a user into a feature of the app.

I'd like to include a deep-link URL in the same QR code.

The use case would be a person that has the app shows the QR code to another person. That person would open their native camera app or a QR code scanner of choice & it would pick up this URL and be navigated to Safari / App Store.

Here is how I am creating my QR Code:

```
    func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        
        var jsonDict = [String: Any]()
        
        let url = "https://mydeeplinkurlhere"
        jsonDict.updateValue(url, forKey: "url")
        jsonDict.updateValue(string, forKey: "xyz")
        
        guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [.prettyPrinted]) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
                
        // Input the data
        qrFilter.setValue(jsonData, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        // Get the output image
        guard let qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return nil}
        
        // Scale the image
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 12, y: 12)
        let scaledQrImage = qrImage.transformed(by: transform)
        // Do some processing to get the UIImage
        let context = CIContext()
        guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(scaledQrImage, from: scaledQrImage.extent) else { return nil }
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        
        return processedImage
    }
```

Update:

The above code is getting me much closer to my desired result.

I am able to split this up if the QR code is scanned in the app and use what I need.

My question now is this:

If a user were to scan using their camera app, it's going to spit out what the JSON is.

So they would see both of the key-value pairs. I don't need them to see all of that. In this scenario, I'd only need them to see the URL and/or a custom message.

Can that part be edited? Meaning, what is displayed when scanning a QR Code?

Or can the website just auto-open vs. seeing the notification?

Comment: You are describing an App Clip? https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/

Comment: @matt They may want to use App Clip in the future. They are wanting this QR code update for right now. I've looked into trying NSKeyedArchiver and just adding each item as a key-value pair, but my QR code looks crazy and I don't get any response from the iPhone camera scan.

Comment: But you cannot send a deep link from within your own app, so I don’t get what the goal is.

Comment: So there are multiple user types. One user type can create a QR code. So the goal is they would create their QR code, then show it to someone who may not have the app. That person would scan the code with their camera, it picks up the deep link URL and directs them to where they can download the app. If they both had the app the QR code would direct them to another screen in the app.

Comment: @matt I'm much closer now to the result I am wanting. My new question is can the output text of a QR code be modified? So right now if I were to use my iPhone camera and scan I would just get a dump of the JSON and see everything I have added there. In this case, I only want to show that URL or maybe a custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store any kind of object in qr code, in your situation you can send several information in your qr code by dictionary or array type, here is the code:

```
func generateQRCode(from dictionary: [String: String]) -> UIImage? {
    guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
    guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dictionary, requiringSecureCoding: false) else { return nil }
    qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    guard let qrImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return nil}

    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
    let scaledQrImage = qrImage.transformed(by: transform)
    let context = CIContext()
    guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(scaledQrImage, from: scaledQrImage.extent) else { return nil }
    let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)

    return processedImage
}
```

And here is your model and how do you call that method:

```
let dictionary: [String: String] = [
    "message" : "some message string here",
    "link" : "https://google.com"
]

YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.image = generateQRCode(from: dictionary)
```

You are completely free to change your data model, but scanning a qr code is different story, check it out: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code

I hope that will be useful, Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks! For the most part I have it working. Two things I am looking into now are: 1.) Customoze the output once it's scanned. So right now if you scanned with the camera you'd see "message" : "abc", "link" : "google.com". I don't want all of that displayed. Or, can the URL be automatically opened once scanned?

Comment: Yes you can do that, after json parsed in the qr code you can send the url in the qr code and open the link automatically in the browser or webview by one line code in your application: UIApplication.shared.open(YOUR_URL_HERE) , but if you want to only share this qr code by device camera and open url automatically you can not do that by default cam application in ios

Comment: By the way, if my answer has been solve your problem, please gimme a upvote for respect for labour, this can be improve my motivation to answer the questions, as you know :) happy coding!

Comment: Gotcha. Yea, the URL will only be used for marketing type purposes. So someone who uses the app shows the QR code to someone else and when they scan with their camera it'll either open to safari / app store, or if they forgot they have the app installed it'll auto open the app.

Comment: Can a custom output message be generated for a QR Code?

Comment: actually, if you are trying to create a qr code for the user to download your application, you can do this by online free generators, chekc this out: https://www.qr-code-generator.com/

Comment: or if you are trying to generate a qr code to commincation by application to application you can show custom output message and any kind of action like opening url as I mantioned earlier

Comment: Can't use anything like that. For a better UX this would need to be managed by this one QR code that is generated in the app. It's unique per user but each would have the same url. I just don't want the other data the QR code has to display when scanned via Camera or some other QR scanner app.

Comment: I  got the point, but actually if you want to open an url and at the same time you share different data from the device which one has qr code, you can't hide to default cam appliation to your output message or customization, maybe you need to solve this problem in server side,

Comment: It's appearing that the only way to customization output information is using newline operator in string, replace your qrFilter line by this in the codebase: qrFilter.setValue("Hello World :\n\nhttps://google.com \nUserData: \(UUID().uuidString)".data(using: .ascii), forKey: "inputMessage")

Comment: in this way maybe you can hide your unnecessary information from the user and show them by one line information in the local notification and thay can access your url by tapping